# CakePHP 3.5 doesn't build route when using routing prefix and path

Tags: routes, cakephp-3.0, prefix

I got a problem with CakePHP router (3.5) when using prefix and $options[path].

So my routes definitions look like:

```
Router::prefix('RestrictedArea', ['path' => '/my-account'], function($routes) {
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'index']);
    $routes->connect('/login', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
    $routes->connect('/register', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'register']);
    $routes->connect('/logout', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'logout']);
    /* More routes here */
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

And in my view:

```
echo $this->Html->link( __('Login'), ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login', 'prefix' => 'RestrictedArea']);
```

This results in a Cake\Routing\Exception\MissingRouteException.

If I do not specify *['path' => '/my-account']* as $options of the Router::prefix method, It builds route as expected (but with "/restricted_area" as url prefix).

If I add manually the two standard routes instead of the fallbacks, like:

```
$routes->connect('/:controller', ['action' => 'index', 'prefix' => 'RestrictedArea'], ['routeClass' => DashedRoute::class]);
$routes->connect('/:controller/:action/*', ['prefix' => 'RestrictedArea'], ['routeClass' => DashedRoute::class]);
```

I got no longer the MissingRouteException ONLY when I manually add prefix to the *$routes->connect* method. And the produced login URL is */my-account/users/login* when expected is */my-account/login*

So, the only way that is working for me, is to specify prefix for each *$routes->connect* methods in my *Router::prefix scope*. So the code below is working fine...

```
Router::prefix('RestrictedArea', ['path' => '/my-account'], function($routes) {
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'index', 'prefix' => 'RestrictedArea']);
    $routes->connect('/login', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login', 'prefix' => 'RestrictedArea']);
    ...
});
```

... but it looks not very good as I have to repeat and repeat prefix, even I'm in the prefix scope.

Any experts in CakePHP routing here?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Is "RestrictedArea" a plugin? I'm curious if you can access it if you renamed it to just "restricted" lets remove inflection from the equation for right now.

Comment: Seems like you put your finger on the bug !
With just "Restricted" as prefix, the Router builds routes as expected. So the problem comes effectively from the prefix inflection.  
As I'm not attached to "RestrictedArea", I can leave just "Restricted", so thank you very much !

Comment: And the prefix must be "restricted" (lower case), not "Restricted"

Comment: upvote me brah! If you want to try it, I am curious if either "restricted-area" or "restricted_area" works for prefixes as well.